# Why am I getting "missing return statement" error in Java even though I have return statement and exception in thread main error in 2nd class?

Tags: java

For example, I am getting the error here- this is just a snippet. I got the error 3 times in 3 different operators.

```
   public boolean delete(String name) {
      for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
         if (directory[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            directory[i] = null;
            return true;
         }   
         else
            return false;
      }
   }
```

I also have the same error here:

```
   public boolean add(String name) {
      if (directory.length == 1024)
         return false;
      for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
         if (directory[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name))
            return false;
         else
            directory[directorySize++] = name;
            return true;
      }
   }
```

And then in my second class (the user interface portion), I keep getting this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Directory

Here is the entire code for that class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class DirectoryWithObjectDesign {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   String directoryDataFile  = "Directory.txt";
   Directory d = new Directory(directoryDataFile);
   Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Directory Server is Ready!");
   System.out.println("Format: command name");
   System.out.println("Enter ^Z to end");
   while (stdin.hasNext()) {
      String command = stdin.next();
      String name = stdin.next();
      if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("find")) {
         if (d.inDirectory(name))
            System.out.println(name + " is in the directory");
         else 
            System.out.println(name + " is NOT in the directory");
      }
      else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
         if (d.add(name))
            System.out.println(name + " added");
         else 
            System.out.println(name + " cannot add! " + "no more space or already in directory");
      }
      else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
         if (d.delete(name))
            System.out.println(name + " deleted");
         else
            System.out.println(name + " NOT in directory");
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("bad command, try again");
      }
   }
   }
}
```

And here is the code for my directory class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Directory {
   //public static void main(String[] args) {
   final int maxDirectorySize = 1024;
   String directory[] = new String[maxDirectorySize];
   int directorySize = 0;
   File directoryFile = null;
   Scanner directoryDataIn = null;

   public Directory(String directoryFileName) {
      directoryFile = new File(directoryFileName);
      try {
         directoryDataIn = new Scanner(directoryFile);
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("File is not found, exiting!" + directoryFileName);
         System.exit(0);
      }
      while (directoryDataIn.hasNext()) {
         directory[directorySize++] = directoryDataIn.nextLine();
      }
   }
   public boolean inDirectory(String name) {
      for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
         if (directory[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name)) 
            return true;
         else 
            return false;
      }
   }
   public boolean add(String name) {
      if (directory.length == 1024)
         return false;
      for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
         if (directory[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name))
            return false;
         else
            directory[directorySize++] = name;
            return true;
      }
   }          

   public boolean delete(String name) {
      for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
         if (directory[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            directory[i] = null;
            return true;
         }   
         else
            return false;
      }
   }

   public void closeDirectory() {
      directoryDataIn.close();
      PrintStream directoryDataOut = null;
      try {
          directoryDataOut = new PrintStream(directoryFile);
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.printf("File %s not found, exiting!", directoryFile);
         System.exit(0);
      }
      String originalDirectory[] = {"Mike","Jim","Barry","Cristian","Vincent","Chengjun","susan","ng","serena"};
      if (originalDirectory == directory)
         System.exit(0);
      else
         for (int i = 0; i < directorySize; i++)
            directoryDataOut.println(directory[i]);
         directoryDataOut.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: You need a `return` also after the `for-loop`.

Comment: In your first two functions if the for loop does not execute then the return statements will not be hit.

Comment: what kind of return statement would I need to put though because it seems everything I  need I put into the loop... is it possible to return null? @suboptimal

Comment: You need to return a `boolean` value for the case that `directory.length` is zero. For example in your `delete(String)` method you should add `return `false;` as last statement in the method. `null` would be not a valid value in this method.

Answer (score 5):

The point is that the compiler can't know if your for loop will be entered at all. Therefore you need a final return **after** the end of the for loop, too. In other words: any path that can possibly be taken within your method needs a final return statement. One easy way to achieve this ... is to have **only one** return statement; and put that on the last line of the method. This could look like:

```
 Object getSomething() {
   Object rv = null; // rv short for "returnValue"
   for (int i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
     if (whatever) {
       rv = godKnowsWhat;
     } else {
       rv = IdontCare;
     }
   }
   return rv;
 }
```

In your second example, the indenting seems to indicate that you have a return in the else statement

```
        directory[directorySize++] = name;
        return true;
```

But when you look closer, you will realize that there are TWO statements after the else

```
 else
        directory[directorySize++] = name;
        return true;
```

So this actually reads like

```
 else
        directory[directorySize++] = name;
 return true;
```

Meaning: **always** put {braces} around all your blocks, even for (supposedly) one-liner then/else lines. That helps to avoid such mistakes, when a one-liner turns into a two-liner (or vice versa ;-)

The "NoClassDefFoundException" means: within the classpath that is specified to java ... there is no class Directory.class

To resolve that, you should study what the java classpath is about; and how to set it correctly.

Comment: I see what you mean about the braces. I fixed that just now. But I am still a bit confused about the return statement. Could I just return null and that will fix the error? I thought in this case, the for loop will always be entered so how should I go about this?

Comment: It is like a said: the **compiler** does **not** know if the loop will ever be entered. Say for example ... for (int i=0; i < someArray.length; i++) ... and someArray length is 0 ... then the body of the for loop is never entered. My updated answer shows you a technique (one return statement only) that works best in 99% of all cases.